# g++ Fatal Error when using Sublime Text 2 to Build C++ Code

Tags: c++, sublimetext2

I am new to Sublime Text 2 and am trying to get it to build and run a simple C++ program but I am running into some errors.

I have the MinGW C++ compiler installed and set the path, however, I am still getting an error when I try to build it:

> g++: error: : No such file or directory
>
> g++: fatal error: no input files

I'm not sure what I should do in order to correct the problem, and info would be super helpful!
Thanks!

Comment: Can you open a command prompt and run `g++`? If not, then your path is not set correctly.

Answer (score 2):

What's your .sublime-build file like?

I use this one and it works just fine.

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "-Wall","-time","-g", "-std=c++11", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",


    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["${file_path}/${file_base_name}"]
        }
    ]
}
```